# ¿Cómo parar la ejecución de un trozo de código si no termina en menos de x segundos? (java)

Tags: java

Necesito que un trozo de código se ejecute en menos de 8 segundos y si no, se pare la ejecución del código automáticamente, lance una excepción y siga el programa principal ejecutándose,

```
public static double pruebas(double n) {
    int numPruebas = 40;
    double media=1;
    Temporizador t = new Temporizador();
    
    **for (int i=0; i<numPruebas; i++) {
        t.reiniciar();
        t.iniciar();
        probar.prueba(n);
        t.parar();
        media*=t.tiempoPasado();
    }**
    
    
                                 return Math.pow(media, 1.0/numPruebas);}
```

Lo que está entre (**) necesito que se pare a los 8 segundos.

¿Con qué herramienta podría hacerlo?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo este código que permite hacer un temporizador del tiempo que quieras, aunque ya lo he puesto a 8 segundos.
Te he dejado comentado donde debería ir la llamada a tu función o puedes integrarlo dentro de tu función eso como tu veas.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;
```

public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int countdownStarter = 8; //el tiempo maximo para ejecutarse

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(countdownStarter); //te dejo esto para que veas como pasa el tiempo
            countdownStarter--;
            
           //EL CODIGO QUE SE EJECUTE EN X TIEMPO

            if (countdownStarter < 0) {
                System.out.println("Timer Over!");
                scheduler.shutdown();
            }
        }
    };
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, SECONDS);
}
```

}